# How to get the filename from a cfhttp get request?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

If I run the following code to get an image from Medium's site:

```
<cfhttp url="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/600/1*3j1McX-y1rvKewzI2gWc_w.png" 
method="get" useragent="#CGI.http_user_agent#" getasbinary="yes">
```

I then want to save the image with the same name that they used i.e. `1*3j1McX-y1rvKewzI2gWc_w.png`.

How can I get the name of the file from the cfhttp request? I looked in the `cfhttp.header` for any sign of the content-disposition attribute but can't find it.

Comment: What about getting the filename from the requested URL?

Comment: I wonder if the fact that the file name has a `*` will be a problem. Does OS that you are running allow for a file name with a `*`?

Comment: @Beginner Because the URL doesn't always contain the filename exactly. It could be generated programmatically by their server. I think Adobe Scene7 does that.

Comment: @JamesAMohler What I plan to do is get the filename and then clean it up using REReplace to remove all non alphanumeric characters

Comment: @Beginner How do I use the content-disponsition header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are getting these URLs dynamically, why not just parse it for the filename first, then apply that to the filename attribute?

```
<cfset filename1 = ListLast("https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/600/1*3j1McX-y1rvKewzI2gWc_w.png","/") />

<cfhttp url="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/600/1*3j1McX-y1rvKewzI2gWc_w.png" 
method="get" useragent="#CGI.http_user_agent#" getasbinary="yes" path="whateverpath" filename="#filename1#>
```

Comment: this is something I thought about originally but many URLs provided by users don't contain a direct link to an image filename with a file extension. They sometimes point to a strange URL that generates an image dynamically like adobe scene7

Comment: I couldn't work out any better way so went with this solution. Thanks TRose, voted as answer.

Comment: Use the `fileGetMimeType` function after downloading the file to guess the file extension in case you don't have one. That's your only chance.

Comment: @Alex thats exactly what I've done :) cfhttp.mimetype gives me the file type.